# SQL to identify initial dates for a product that changes from active to cancelled status

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that records the following items:

1. product_id
2. product_status
3. date

Products can exist in the following product statuses: pending, active, or canceled. Only one status can exist per date per product code. A status and product code is inserted for each and every day a product exists.

Utilizing SQL I'd like to be able to identify the initial cancellation dates for a product that cancels more than once in a given time frame.

i.e. if a product is active for 3 days and then cancels for 3 days and then is active again for 3 days and then cancels again for another 3 days.

I'd like to be able to identify day 1 of the 2 cancellation periods.

Comment: What would make this question even better would be some demo data and table ddl so we could simply copy it into our dbms and work on a solution. Heard of slq-fiddle? Still +1 for a clear description. Please add what you tried to solve this (your query) - SO is about correcting things, not programming whole sqls for you.

Comment: Thanks mate! Will do next time.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd get the crystal ball out for this one. This sounds like a Gaps and Islands question. There's plenty of answers on how to do this on the internet, however, this might be what you're after:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (product_id int,
                      product_status varchar(10),
                      [date] date); --blargh

INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES (1,'active', '20170101'),
       (1,'active', '20170102'),
       (1,'active', '20170103'),
       (1,'cancelled', '20170104'),
       (1,'cancelled', '20170105'),
       (1,'cancelled', '20170106'),
       (1,'active', '20170107'),
       (1,'pending', '20170108'),
       (1,'active', '20170109'),
       (1,'cancelled', '20170110'),
       (2,'pending', '20170101'),
       (2,'active', '20170102'),
       (2,'cancelled', '20170103'),
       (2,'cancelled', '20170104');
GO

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

WITH Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id
                              ORDER BY [date]) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, product_status
                              ORDER BY [date]) AS Grp 
    FROM #Sample)
SELECT product_id, MIN([date]) AS cancellation_start
FROM Groups
WHERE product_status = 'cancelled'
GROUP BY Grp, product_id
ORDER BY product_id, cancellation_start;

GO
DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

If not, then see Patrick Artnet's comment.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I expected. Thanks for the help mate.